# google chart column name override

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have used google chart in loop. I am getting data from api and i am printing charts in loop, it is working properly but the column name below bars are getting override, it work fine for single bar but for multiple bar it is not adjust their names.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart','bar']});                
     $http.get(PUBLIC_URL+'apiname/'+$scope.form.isno).then(function success(response) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawBasic(response.data); });

     });                   

     function drawBasic(chartData) {
         angular.forEach(chartData, function(value, key) {
                var chartDataArray = [];
                chartDataArray.push(['Bar', 'Index']);
                angular.forEach(value, function(v, k) {                     
                    chartDataArray.push([v.name, parseInt(v.data)]);                        
                });
                //console.log(chartDataArray);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartDataArray);

                var title = 'Revenue vs Profit';

                var options = {
                    title : title,
                    legend: { position: 'none' }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"+(key+1)));
                // var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            });
        }
```

chartDataArray sample :

```
[
  ['Bar', 'Index'],
  ['2012',  900],
  ['2013',  1000],
  ['2014',  1170],
  ['2015',  1250],
  ['2016',  1530]
]
```

Comment: @WhiteHat i have updated my question. chartData is object where multipe value as present am creating charDataArray as fromated array for chart

Comment: so with the posted data, are you getting multiple charts with a single bar?